# Implementing list (lisp) with limited procedures

Tags: list, lisp, clisp, cons

I'm currently working on a clisp assignment making a basic address book. However, the caveat to this assignment is I can only use cons, car, cdr, cond, if, eq, assoc and setf to complete the assignment...

I decided early on to simply implement my own list and append procedures to simplify the process, but that isn't working particularly well. Frankly, I'm lost on how to generate a non-dotted list using only the above procedures.

Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
(defun create-entry (name email phone-number address)
  (list (cons 'name name)
        (cons 'email email)
        (cons 'phone-number phone-number)
        (cons 'address address)))
```

Obviously I can't use list here, and my only solution thus far has ben to cons name and email, cons phone-number to that and cons address to that which isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

TL;DR Is there a way to implement the list procedure using only cons, car, cdr, cond, if, eq, assoc and setf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list is just a bunch of cons cells, linked one to the next, with `nil` as the last cdr. Therefore you could implement your `create-entry` function like this:

```
(defun create-entry (name email phone-number address)
  (cons (cons 'name name)
    (cons (cons 'email email)
      (cons (cons 'phone-number phone-number)
        (cons (cons 'address address)
          nil)))))
```

Alternatively, you could implement your own version of the `list` function like this:

```
(defun your-own-list (&rest l) l)

(defun create-entry (name email phone-number address)
  (your-own-list 
    (cons 'name name)
    (cons 'email email)
    (cons 'phone-number phone-number)
    (cons 'address address)))
```

But that feels like it's going against the spirit of the assignment.

Comment: Man, I don't know how I goofed it up. I thought I'd done something similar to your first suggestion, but ended up with a list within a list within a list etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Already checked but just so you know, eventually you'd do:

```
(defun create-entry (name email phone-number address)
  `((name  . ,name)
    (email . ,email)
    (phone-number . ,phone-number)
    (address . ,address)))
```

which uses `quasiquote` as convenient syntax to create structured lists.

Comment: nice! :) (though quasiquote isn't part of the allowed *repertoire* here).